# Javascript - return function of a function using parent function parameters

Tags: javascript

I'm executing the bellow javascript code :

```
var distances = [2,3];
var ids = 0

 for (var i=0; i < sub.length; i++) {
        url = // some value 
        dis = distances[i+ids];
        jsonGET(url,[],test(data,dis));
      }

 function test(data,dist)  {
  return function() {
   console.log(dist);
   }
  }
```

Inside the for loop (that iterates 2 times because sub.length = 2), there's a call to jsonGET function that executes **test** function in case of successful connection to the given url.

**dis** value is passed to test function within the jsonGET call.

Logically, console.log(dist) should display the value 2 then 3. It actually does when I write ir before the return statement. 
But when I write console.log(dist) as it's shown on the above code. I'm getting this very strange display

[image]

the code is refreshed every 30 sec and it seems like it's randomly alternating between (2,3) ( which is the logical result ) and (3,2) which is inversed.

I'm stuck here, need an explanation for it.

Comment: We can presume `jsonGET()` is asynchronous right? Your function will only get called once `jsonGET()` has done its thing right? So the question should be, is there a reason to think that `jsonGET()` will always finish in the order in which it's called?

Comment: Is the third parameter for jsonGET a call back function of the asynchronus api call??

Comment: yes it's a callback of asynch api call